# invalid date at d3.scaleTime()

Tags: javascript, d3.js, time-series, dataset

I am really new at js and d3 and I am trying to use a dataset with timeseries but its not working. As I am building this dataset myself in pandas I have both encoded in json with and without `date_format='iso'` that means that I can use `"2019-01-02T00:00:00.000Z"` or `1546387200000` for this answer and yes, this is the 1st entry of my data

What I am doing right now is:

```
data = _.map(data, d => {
const ts = d.data_emprestimo;
const date = new Date(ts).toISOString();
...
return{
date,
```

If I do not do this, instead of `2019-01-02` it returns a day before like `2019-01-01`

After that:

```
const [minDate, maxDate] = d3.extent(data, d => d.date);
console.log(minDate,maxDate)
```

And still working. return the correct date but when I use:

```
const xScale = d3.scaleTime().domain([
d3.timeYear.floor(minDate), d3.timeYear.ceil(maxDate)
...
console.log(xScale.domain(), xScale.range())
```

the console log return an Invalid Date.

Whats the proper solution to use a dataset like this and pass the correct date?

this is the output I am getting right now

[image: console log]

Comment: Why not `d3.scaleTime().domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.date))` ?

Comment: I tried but it still return `Invalid date`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`d3.scaleTime`](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#time-scales) takes dates in the domain function.

In the shared code sample, it is passed a set of strings, this is causing the problem.

As shown in the snippet below, the range is sect correctly whenever date objects are used in the domain function, and the day values are correct.

```js
const ts = "2019-01-02T00:00:00.000Z";
const date = new Date(ts);

const data = [{date: date}]


const xScale = d3.scaleTime().domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.date))

console.log(xScale.domain(), xScale.range())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ok. My first entrie of json file is `{"0":{"data_emprestimo":"2019-01-02T00:00:00.000Z","tipo_vinculo_usuario":"ALUNO DE GRADUA\u00c7\u00c3O","freq":86}` but if I didnt use `.toISOString()` in `new Date()` it returns `Tue Jan 01 2019 22:00:00 GMT-0200 (Horário de Verão de Brasília` which is 1 day before the actual date/entry of my dataset

Comment: The dates should be used as date objects in the time scale domain. Whenever you display the dates, then you should format them as desired.

Comment: So that means my code was correct all the time? I understand `.toISOString()` is to display but I though since the display was incorrect, the entries when I pass `new Date()` was incorrect too. Sorry, as I mention I am really new at js and d3.